# How to split String using Regex specific String

Tags: java, regex, kotlin

I have a value(String) like "BLD00000001BLD00000002 BLD00000003, BLD00000004".

I want to use Regex `"""^BLD\d{8}"""`

but it didn't work..

I want to return results like (BLD00000001','BLD00000002','BLD00000003 ... )

```
        var regex = Regex("""[\{\}\[\]\/?.,;:|\) *~`!^\-_+<>@\#$%&\\\=\(\'\"]""")
        val cvrtBldIds = bldIds.split(regex)

        if (cvrtBldIds.joinToString(separator="").length % 11 != 0) {
            throw BadRequestException("MSG000343", listOf("빌딩Id", "BLD[숫자8자리]"))
        } else {
            val res = cvrtBldIds
                .filter{it.startsWith("BLD")}   // BLD로 시작하는 것만 추출
                .joinToString(separator = "','")      // 아이디 앞뒤로 ',' 붙이기 
            bldIds = res
            var sb = StringBuffer()
            sb.append("'")
            sb.append(bldIds)
            sb.append("'")
            input.bldId = sb.toString()
        }
```

Comment: Try omitting the anchor `BLD\d{8}`

Comment: How can I use regex and split without whitespace ...?

Comment: If you want those matches, you could use `BLD\d{8}` and extract the matches instead of using split.

Comment: var bldId = "BLD00000001BLD00000002 BLD00000003, BLD00000004"
        val regex1 = Regex("""[\{\}\[\]\/?.,;:|\) *~`!^\-_+<>@\#${'$'}%&\\\=\(\'\"]""")
        val a = bldId.replace(regex1, "")
        val regex2 = Regex("""BLD\d{8}""")
        val b = a.matches(regex2)
        println("${b}")
but it returns false...

Comment: Does https://stackoverflow.com/a/61186817/3832970 solve your problem?

Answer (score 0):

Do it as follows:

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.regex.Matcher;
import java.util.regex.Pattern;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String str = "BLD00000001BLD00000002 BLD00000003, BLD00000004";
        List<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
        Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("BLD\\d{8}");
        Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(str);
        while (matcher.find()) {
            list.add(matcher.group());
        }
        System.out.println(list);
    }
}
```

**Output:**

```
[BLD00000001, BLD00000002, BLD00000003, BLD00000004]
```

**Notes:**

1. `BLD\\d{8}` means starting with `BLD` and then 8 digits.
2. Java regex tutorial: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/regex/

Answer (score 0):

Seems you want to **split** on a space, or a comma-space combo, or between a digit and the text `BLD`. The following regex can do that:

```regex
,?\s|(?<=\d)(?=BLD)
```

See [regex101](https://regex101.com/r/g6qOcc/1) for demo.

Answer (score 0):

Here is how you can extract `BLD\d{8}` pattern matches in Kotlin using [.findall()](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.text/-regex/find-all.html):

```
val text = """"BLD00000001BLD00000002 BLD00000003, BLD00000004"."""
val matcher = """BLD\d{8}""".toRegex()
println(matcher.findAll(text).map{it.value}.toList() )
// => [BLD00000001, BLD00000002, BLD00000003, BLD00000004]
```

See the [Kotlin demo](https://rextester.com/KOSVQ49497)